# Getters and Setters don't work when getting ScriptableObject from a method

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have this two classes:

```
public class JavaScriptObject extends ScriptableObject {

    private int someInt;

    public int jsGet_someInt()
    {
        return someInt;
    }

    public void jsSet_someInt(int value)
    {
        someInt = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() 
    {
        return "JSO";
    }   
}

public class FunctionPool {
    public JavaScriptObject getJso() {
        return new JavaScriptObject();
    }
}
```

I have this script:

```
var jso = fp.getJso();
jso.someInt += 1;
var i = jso.someInt;
```

The second and the third line doesn't work. The problem is that the jso object doesn't know any setters or getters, so the getter returns undefined and the setter doesn't do anything. They also don't work if I create the jso object with ScriptableObject.putProperty. It only works if I create it within the script like this:

```
var jso = new JSO();
```

So any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I don't really see that you used either setter or getter. You should do: - `jso.jsGet_someInt(jso.jsSet_someInt() + 1)`. And why have you used such a horrible name for your getter and setter? Just using `getSomeInt()` and `setSomeInt(int)` would do.

Comment: jso.someint = 1; should use the jsSet_someInt method with 1 as parameter and var i = jso.someInt; should use the jsGet_someInt method.

Comment: @CubeX2.. And why do you think you can access a `private` variable from outside the class. And more surpisingly, why do you think, accessing a variable by its name will invoke its accessor methods?

Comment: Because this works:

   `var jso = new JSO();
    jso.someInt++;`

Comment: @CubeX2.. In that line, you have just created an object of your `JSO` class. You can't access a class's private fields directly on it's object. You need to access it by invoking the public accessor methods. `getter` and `setter`, should be called explicitly.

Comment: As far as I know, setters and getters must follow the "getFoo" and "setFoo" naming convention unless you've got your own BeanInfo class somewhere. Otherwise you have to call the functions by name explicitly.

Comment: Changing the methods to getsomeInt and setsomeInt don't work, too.
 
@Rhoit Jain If I make the someInt field public I can't access it, too.